# Google AUTH API Returning 500 Error

Tags: api, authentication, google-authentication

This endpoint call has always worked:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo

Nothing changed.  But today around 12:30ET it gives us the following response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Google Services admins said they could not answer and to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a similar spike in 500s on login requests around the same time. It's possible it's just a random hiccup in their services. https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=22&iid=63152ed689097a6944dcdf3f15a12692 reports there was some temporary downtime logging into Hangouts for some users at around that same window -- might be the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the Google Hangouts service disruption info.

Do you know where I could find our about Google's AUTH service?

[https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo)

Comment: No idea, unfortunately. It doesn't appear to be available on their app status page.